# Laravel / ffmpeg headers not found on centos 7

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, centos7, ffmpeg-php

I want to use `ffmpeg` on laravel project. OS is `centos7` and panel is `DirectAdmin` and using `php 8.1`

> PHP Version 8.1.12

I installed `ffmpeg` on centos 7 and I get `ffmpeg`

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.13 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

But in `phpinfo` and `php -m` ffmpeg not listed! yet so I noticed should configure ffmpeg on php then I run:

```
./configure && make
```

on `/usr/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0`

But result is:

> checking for ffmpeg headers... configure: error: ffmpeg headers not
> found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the
> --enable-shared option

Then I run:

```
./configure --enable-shared
```

But still the same error.

In laravel project I got error:

```
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/home/site.com/public_html/laravel/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php"
line: 149
message: "file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/bin/ffmpeg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/opt/alt/php81/usr/shar...
```

After many hours searching and testing still I couldn't fix this issue, any suggestion?

Comment: You can check this guide, it will install ffmpeg with shared libraries. 
I have tested it on Amazon Linux 2023 which is not too different from centos.
If you get any error, let me know happy to help
https://mirzabilal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-linux-from-source